# Does a Gitolite administration plugin for Redmine 2.2 exist?

Tags: redmine, gitolite

Once upon a time there was some neat plugin for the old version of Redmine enabling Gitosis administration through the redmine GUI, adding key to users, creating repo, etc...

But some days later, like today, I've been trying to install the last version of Redmine in Ubuntu 12.04 (from the official doc http://www.redmine.org/projects/redmine/wiki/HowTo_Install_Redmine_in_Ubuntu )... That works fine but there nothing I can do to find a working plugin for Gitolite (the Gitosis replacement. Does anybody has any solution or should I resign myself to manual administration of Gitolite ?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can check official Redmine plugins directory: http://www.redmine.org/plugins/redmine_git_hosting